# How to assign value from array to model

Tags: arrays, angular, ngmodel

I have problem with assign from array to model. I want to assign firstName value from userFromDb and assign this value to firstName in model and the same with another values. I don't know how do this :(

> User

```
export interface User{

id:string;
firstName:string;
lastName:string;
email:string;
password:string;
}
```

> UpadateUserComponent.ts

```
userFromDb: Array<Object>;

model:User = {
id: '',
firstName: '',
lastName: '',
email: '',
password: ''}

ngOnInit() {

let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

this.userService.getUser(id).subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result)
  this.userFromDb = result
  console.log(this.userFromDb)
});
```

> UpadateUserComponent.html

```
<div>
    <form action="" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="saveUser()" novalidate>
        <div>
            <label for="firstName">First Name: </label>
            <input [(ngModel)]="model.firstName" type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="lastName">Last Name: </label>
            <input [(ngModel)]="model.lastName" type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Name" >
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="email">Email: </label>
            <input [(ngModel)]="model.email" type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Name" >
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="password">Password: </label>
            <input [(ngModel)]="model.password" type="text" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Name" >
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what your database structure looks like, but lets say it is the same as your frontend...

- First I am not sure why your `userFromDb` is an array, would it return more than one user?

If you just want to insert the values then the simplest would be:

```
this.userService.getUser(id).subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result)
  this.userFromDb = result
  this.model.firstName = this.userFromDB[0].firstName
  // same with other values here
  console.log(this.userFromDb)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.userService.getUser(id).subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result);
  this.userFromDb:User = result[0];
  console.log(this.userFromDb);
});
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <form action="" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="saveUser()" novalidate>
        <div>
            <label for="firstName">First Name: </label>
            <input [(ngModel)]="userFromDb.firstName" type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="lastName">Last Name: </label>
            <input [(ngModel)]="model.lastName" type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Name" >
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="email">Email: </label>
            <input [(ngModel)]="userFromDb.email" type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Name" >
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="password">Password: </label>
            <input [(ngModel)]="userFromDb.password" type="text" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Name" >
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```